# Connection was interrupted to zoom UI server in Xcode running on Device

Tags: ios, sqlite, mapkit

I have absolutely NO CLUE, what this error means:

> |error| Connection was interrupted to zoom UI server.

I'm getting this error when I try to insert data in Sqlite. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that this question is being discussed, albeit tangentially, [on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298819/3001761) - it would be helpful if you could provide some more information about what leads to this error (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).